# bottom bar button crash

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have been trying to figure out why suddenly my bottom bar navigation button for a particular activity causes crashes.

On MainActivity, I have the following bottom bar nav:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_events:
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_events);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_offpeak:
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_offpeak);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_deals:
                Intent reservationsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DealsHomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(reservationsIntent);
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_bookings);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_me:
                Intent memberProfileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MemberProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(memberProfileIntent);
                //logout();
                //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_me);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Then, my activity is instantiated like all my other activities, like the MemberProfileActivity.class.

However pushing the button to get to MemberProfileActivity.class works as expected on the phone, but when doing this for DealsHomeActivity.class results in a crash with the following logcat:

> 05-27 15:38:40.473 31978-31978/asia.diningcity.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: asia.diningcity.android, PID: 31978
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{asia.diningcity.android/asia.diningcity.android.activities.DealsHomeActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class cannot be instantiated
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2737)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2911)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1608)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6665)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
>        Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class cannot be instantiated
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2911) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1608) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6665) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)

I have been looking at the two activities in Java to see if there are any differences in the onCreate method to start the activity but none.

So I don't understand where this could be coming from.

Please note also this was working fine before, and since then I haven't touched the menu bar or that Deals activity so I don't know what could have caused this.

Comment: Have you added `DealsHomeActivity` to your Manifest?

Comment: also paste MemberProfileActivity & dealsactivity code, make sure class is not an abstract

Comment: please share the code for `DealsHomeActivity.java`

Comment: Amir De helped me fix it, it was the "abstract" keyword in DealsHomeActivity.java that was causing this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe your class is either an abstract class or a private class, abstract or private classes can not be instantiated,

Abstract classes are by definition not instantiable.

if your class is abstract or private, i assume it's something like this

```
private abstract class DealsHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

change to

```
public class DealsHomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: You were right! There was an abstract keyword there, I deleted it and it works now!

Thank you so much! 

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding!